# My Documents Folder Not Opening

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

My friend, who helped used a program called Winareo to add Google Drive to 'This PC' list in windows 10 file explorer, then he also changed the icons for 'My documents'.
However, now, the folder[ 'My documents'. ] doesn't open (occasionally it does after a few minutes).
 It still opens if I access it manually.

I tried restoring defaults both in Winareo and Windows File explorer, but the 'Documents' shortcut just doesn't open.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your My documents folder and see if you changed the default path, if so. Restore it.

[image]